# About Rigid Matrices

Tags: matrices

I want to know the meaning of Rigid matrices and Rigidity of matrices contained in this definition "The rigidity of a matrix A for target rank r is the minimum number of entries of A that must be changed to ensure that the rank of the altered matrix is at most r".
  What is the change that is doing to the elements? with an example

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "What is the change that is doing to the elements? with an example"

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  Perhaps it would be helpful to provide a reference (link or book title) for the *"rigidity of a matrix"*.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.5301.pdf What is the meaning of the Definition 1 and What is the change that is doing to the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a random-ish example.

$$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 1 & -1 & -3\cr 1 & -2 & -1\cr}\ \text{over}\ \mathbb C$$

Its rank is $3$.  The most obvious way to make the rank $2$ is by changing the 
top right $1$ to $0$, but you could change any of the entries $a_{ij}$ except $a_{23}$ and $a_{33}$ to make the rank $2$.  On the other hand, to make the rank $0$ will require changing all seven nonzero entries to $0$.  To make the rank $1$ will require changing at least $3$ entries, I think.  For example, you could change $a_{13}$ to $0$, $a_{23}$ to $-1$ and $a_{32}$ to $-1$.
So $\text{Rig}(A,3) = 0$, $\text{Rig}(A, 2) = 1$, $\text{Rig}(A,1) = 3$, $\text{Rig}(A,0) = 7$.

Comment: This means that the matrix has changed and becomes another one?

Comment: Yes, of course.  To get a different rank it must change.

Comment: When solving equations $A.X=B$ we calculate the rank of the constants matrix $[A|B]$ to get equivalent equations to simplify the solution.
Do we get another equivalent equations when we calculate the rigidity of the constants matrix? and therefore we get more simplified solution?